# Extending/specializing `template<typename T>zero()` to invocable `T`

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to define a function `template<typename T> zero()` and specialize it to various cases.

`zero<T>()` should return

- `static T::zero()` if that exists.
- else `static_cast<T>(0)` if that is defined.

So far so good, as implemented below.

Now I want to extend the template in a sensible way to any `T` that is implicitly convertible to a type of the form `std::function<Y(X...)>`, and should return the corresponding zero-returning function `[](X...){return zero<Y>();}`

What would be the best way to do this?

```
namespace hidden {

    // tag dispatching
    template<int r>
    struct rank : rank<r - 1> {};

    template<>
    struct rank<0> {};

    template<typename T>
    auto zero(rank<2>) -> decltype(T::zero()) {
        return T::zero();
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto zero(rank<1>) -> decltype(static_cast<T>(0)) {
        return static_cast<T>(0);
    }

    // This is where I need help
    template<typename T>
    auto zero(rank<0>) -> std::enable_if_t</* T is implicitly convertible to std::function<Y(X...)> */,T> {
        using Y = // the type returned when an instance of T is invoked
        return []() {
            return zero<Y>();
        };
    }
}

template<typename T>
auto zero() { return hidden::zero<T>(rank<10>{}); }
```

### Edit:

I've resorted for now to repeating the following with concrete signature for each expected signature:

```
template<typename T>
auto zero(rank<0>)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_assignable<std::function<double(double)>, T>::value
    , std::function<double(double)>> {
    using Y = double;
        return []() {
            return zero<Y>();
    };
}
```

but I'm hoping it's possible to replace the copy-pasting with template magic.

Answer (score 1):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with a deduction guide of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides):

```
template <typename T,
          typename F = decltype(std::function{std::declval<T>()}),
          typename Y = typename F::result_type>
F zero(rank<0>) {
    return [](auto&&...) {
        return zero<Y>(rank<10>{});
    };
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77e5eda50ed90a8c)

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you need to write [this trait](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07d5fc4e02bd7943) yourself.

---

Note, however, that this will not work if `T::operator()` is overloaded or represents a function template (including generic lambda expressions).